# IIS website cannot run because of Application Pool user permissions

Tags: iis, permissions, windows-server-2012, application-pools

I'm having the following issue when trying to user an AD group account instead of ApplicationPoolIdentity. When I use ApplicationPoolIdentity everything works fine, but when I use the AD account I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Execution Error

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: 

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException]
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.BeginProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +0
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12336350
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

I tried to use the process monitor to see what was happening and the only thing I got was this:

```
Result: BAD IMPERSONATION
Path: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog
```

I have given full access to the AD account on the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog, but I keep getting the same error.

I'm using IIS 8.5 on Windows 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the AD account you wish to use to the local IIS_IUSRS group on the IIS server.

I believe you have to use an AD user/service account for running app pools, you cannot use an AD security group to run an app pool.

Comment: I tried that, but I still got the same problem. This ended up getting solved by adding the user to the local administrator group. Not very happy with this solution, but the company security policy allowed to do this and apparently some other apps were already working like this.